# Огромные отступы между CardView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Надеюсь тут можно публиковать ссылки , на другие ресурсы, если что не бейте, просто там будет понятнее. Вернемся к проблеме, использовал я [эту](http://androiddocs.ru/cardview-primer-ispolzovaniya/) статью, для создания RecyclerView и CardView. У себя я сделал почти идентично. Но у меня огромные отступы между cardview , вне зависимости от их размеров. Отступы примерно в 300dp, не могу понять в чем причина.

Вот мой ContentMain

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hondle.sweet_story.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

И card_list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="hello"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Классы RecyclerAdapter и MainActivity различаются от статьи только ссылками на активности и все. Что я упустил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашей разметке card_list (логичнее было бы назвать card_item) у внешнего `LinearLayout` стоит высота `match_parent`. Собственно он и устанавливает ее высоту равную размеру экрана. Именно поэтому и получаются большие отступы. Попробуйте поменять на `wrap_content`